# NSNumber to useconds_t in Swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have a `increment: NSNumber`and want to use the `usleep` function. I tried to convert like:

```
let value = increment.intValue
let sec:useconds_t = value as! useconds_t
usleep(sec)
```

The error is that the former cast always fails.

Edit: want to translate the following objective-c code taken from [here](https://github.com/pbernasconi/cordova-progressIndicator/blob/master/src/ios/ProgressIndicator.m#L429):

```
- (void)progressTask:(NSNumber *)increment{

    // get increment value
    int _increment = [increment intValue];

    float progress = 0.0f;
    while (progress < 1.0f) {
        progress += 0.01f;
        self.progressIndicator.progress = progress;

        // increment in microseconds (100000mms = 1s)
        usleep(_increment);
    }
}
```

**How can I get an `useconds_t` from a `NSNumber`?**

Comment: Usually you just use the initialiser methods. e.g. `let sec = useconds_t(value.intValue)`

Comment: @Sulthan Could you pleas provide an equivalent example with  NSTimer?

Comment: I can but that would be a different question.

Comment: @Sulthan Okay here is the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29975663/replace-usleep-with-nstimer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`useconds_t` is just a type alias for `UInt32`, so can simply do

```
let value = increment.unsignedIntValue // returns UInt32
usleep(value)   // no conversion necessary
```

Of course you should never do that on the main UI thread. And even
on background threads there are often better solutions
(such as the GCD methods).

Comment: Please see my edit of the code I want to implement. What would be a better solution?

Comment: @confile: I had only a quick look at that code. It seems that MBProgressHUD (which is used here) calls that method on a background thread, so it is probably OK. (Otherwise it wouldn't work correctly in Objective-C either). But I have no experience with *this* project, so I cannot give a quick advice how to do it differently.

Comment: Should I use the sleep or should I skip it?

Comment: @confile: Sorry, but I don't know that software and cannot say what they are trying to achieve and  how to do it differently. Simply removing the `usleep` will not work. – But if we assume that the code works correctly in Objective-C then you can do the same in Swift.

Answer (score 0):

You can't cast numbers of different types in Swift, but you can initialize a useconds_t from an Int32.

```
let value = increment.intValue
let sec: useconds_t = useconds_t(value)
usleep(sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I tested this so I know it works now:

```
let num = NSNumber(int: 1)
let secs = useconds_t(num.intValue)
```